# Not able to populate Athena script in AWS Lambda

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

```py
import awswrangler as wr

def main():
    
    database = 'temp'
    output_table = 'Output Table'
    output_s3_location = "'s3:Location'"
    output_s3_storage_format = "'Parquet'" # "'TEXTFILE'"  # "'Parquet'"

    
    create_query = "CREATE TABLE " + database + "." + output_table + " \
    WITH ( \
    format = "+output_s3_storage_format+", \
    external_location = "+ output_s3_location +", \
    partitioned_by = ARRAY['run_date'])  AS "
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO "+database+"."+output_table+" "
    select_query = """with temp AS
                    (SELECT CONCAT(period,' ',date1) AS new_Date,text,text1
                    FROM
                    (SELECT Substr(CAST(year AS varchar),3,4) AS date1,
                    test,
                    text1,
                    CASE
                    WHEN period='JAN' THEN 'Jan'
                    WHEN period='FEB' THEN 'Feb'
                    WHEN period='MAR' THEN 'Mar'
                    WHEN period='APR' THEN 'Apr'
                    WHEN period='MAY' THEN 'May'
                    WHEN period='JUN' THEN 'Jun' 
                    WHEN period='JUL' THEN 'Jul' 
                    WHEN period='AUG' THEN 'Aug' 
                    WHEN period='SEP' THEN 'Sep' 
                    WHEN period='OCT' THEN 'Oct' 
                    WHEN period='NOV' THEN 'Nov' 
                    WHEN period='DEC' THEN 'Dec' 
                    END AS period 
                    FROM Table_Name
                    WHERE text1='Car' ) ) ,
                    temp1 AS
                    (SELECT temp.* from A left join temp
                    ON A.value=temp.value)
                     Select * from temp2";""" 
                    
    if create:
        wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql="DROP TABLE " + database +"." + output_table + ";", database=database, ctas_approach=False)
        wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql=create_query+select_query, database=database, ctas_approach=False)
    else:
        wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql=insert_query+select_query, database=database, ctas_approach=False)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    main()
    return "True"
```

I am getting the below error while writing this script in Lambda function and testing it:

Response:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 24:23: mismatched input '.' expecting {',', ')', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT'}",


  "errorType": "InvalidRequestException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 134, in lambda_handler\n    main()\n",

    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 128, in main\n    wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql=create_query+select_query, database=database, ctas_approach=False)\n",

    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_config.py\", line 263, in wrapper\n    return function(**args)\n",
```

Comment: I suggest that you print the contents of the query string being sent to Athena, and then try running it manually in the Amazon Athena console to identify the SQL error. Are you sure that you can pass multiple commands to Amazon Athena in one command (eg `CREATE TABLE...; SELECT...`)?

Comment: Thank You. I found the error.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! If you think that your solution will help other people, feel free to post it as an Answer. Alternatively, if you think that the question is not beneficial to future readers, feel free to delete it.

Comment: Basically, I had my same query. What I did was that I had removed partitioned_by = ARRAY['run_date'])  AS